# Сигнатура int& foo()=7

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Друзья,

это чисто теоретический вопрос. Подскажите где может быть использована такая функция. Какой в этом практический смысл?

```
int& foo()=7;
```

Детали: тип не принципиален, целый взят просто в качестве примера.

Большое спасибо заранее.

Comment: Эээ... Я надеюсь, это не компилируется?

(Может быть, вы имели в виду `= 0`?)

Comment: нет именно произвольный инт и это не касается чистых вирт методов

Comment: >нет именно произвольный инт и это не касается чистых вирт методов

хорошо, тогда покажите пример кода, где вы это увидели/написали, чтоб это работало

Comment: возможно, там выпало часть кода? и на самом деле там что то вида


    int& foo() {
    //....
    }
    //....
    foo() = 7;

а хитрый человек-редактор решил укоротить.

Comment: А могла выпасть часть буковок из

      int &(*foo)() = (typeof(foo))7;

Comment: @avp - я не вижу практической ценности в подобной записи.

Comment: Как ни странно, я тоже.

Answer (score 1):

Это не компилируется и не должно. Это используется, преимущественно, в книгах, чтобы что-то показать. Практический, не имеет никакого смысла, используется только теоретический.

Comment: @Airhand, а что именно показать-то хотят именно такой записью?